# How Can I read the metadata of files in S3 buckets using spark?

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am slightly new to AWS as well as Spark. I am stuck with a problem. I have a folder in my S3 bucket which contains 2 files named financial_data1.csv and financial_data2.csv. I am trying to read the records from both files and do an upsert.

In order to run the upsert I need to have the timestamp of each record as in which record is the latest. Now my csv files on the record level does not contain the created_timestamp/updated_timestamp type of column.So I have to be dependent upon the last modified time of the file upload in S3 bucket which is nothing but the timestamp of the file when it was uploaded.

Can I read this uploaded time of file from my spark-scala/spark-java code ?

There are currently 2 solutions which are in my mind :

1. Run a lambda to rename the files and add the timestamp in the filename.
2. Read all the files from java/scala code and use the summary object to fetch the last modified date. =

Although I can do both of the above but it will only add another overhead of calling S3 to fetch files first through java/scala code and then reading data through spark.

What I want to do is directly read the file content and it's file name+last modified date. Is this possible ?

Comment: Not sure if there's an easy with to do it. But you can look into implementing your own `DataFrameReader` where you will have access to the S3 object and don't need to access it twice.